# More Efficient Conversion of Archived Python Dict to JSON

Tags: python, json, gzip, converters, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a lot of archive data in python dict format that I am working to convert over to json. I'm interested in speeding this process up if I can and would like to know if anyone has any suggestions. Currently I:

1. take in the gzip compressed data "in multiple files"
2. read them line by line
3. do a literal_eval with ast
4. use json dumps to to create the needed json string
5. query for the date of the line
6. open up a file for appending named by the detected date
7. write the string to the file
8. restart the entire process

Here's my current working code:

```
import gzip
import ast
import json
import glob
import fileinput
from dateutil import parser

line = []

filestobeanalyzed = glob.glob('./data/*.json.gz')

for fileName in filestobeanalyzed:
        inputfilename = fileName
        print inputfilename # to keep track of where I'm at
        for line in fileinput.input(inputfilename, openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed):
                line = line.strip();
                if not line: continue
                try:
                        line = ast.literal_eval(line)
                        line = json.dumps(line)
                except:
                        continue
                date = json.loads(line).get('created_at')
                    if not date: continue
                date_converted = parser.parse(date).strftime('%Y%m%d')
                outputfilename = gzip.open(date_converted, "a")
                outputfilename.write(line)
                outputfilename.write("\n")

outputfilename.close()
```

There must be a more efficient way of doing this, I'm just not seeing it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First profile it with http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/ it will give you timings line by line, you can also try to multithreaded it, use multiprocessing pool and map a list of files to your function.

Though I have feeling IO maybe an issue, though again that depends on the size of the files.

```
# Assuming you have a large dictionary across a multi-part gzip files.
def files_to_be_analyzed(files):
    lines = ast.literal_eval("".join([gzip.open(file).read() for file in files]))
    date = lines['created_at']
    date_converted = parser.parse(date).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    output_file = gzip.open(date_converted, "a")
    output_file.write(lines + "\n")
    output_file.close()
```

Im still not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but try to read and write as few times as possible since IO is a killer. If you need to work on multiple directories then look at multithreading it something like this.

```
import gzip
import ast
import json
import glob
import fileinput
from dateutil import parser
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Assuming you have a large dictionary across a multi-part gzip files.
def files_to_be_analyzed(files):
    lines = ast.literal_eval("".join([gzip.open(file).read() for file in files]))
    date = lines['created_at']
    date_converted = parser.parse(date).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    output_file = gzip.open(date_converted, "a")
    output_file.write(lines + "\n")
    output_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes = 5) # Or what ever number of cores you have
    directories = ['/path/to/this/dire', '/path/to/another/dir']
    pool.map(files_to_be_analyzed, [glob.glob(path) for path in directories])
    pools.close()
    pools.join()
```

Comment: My goal is to maintain an archive of historical data though the management of multiple format structures: ie: python dict, json, etc. This allows me to make use of other tools in other languages that can only read specific formats. I actually wasn't familiar with the line_profiler, that's very useful, thank you!